# inter-role azure: Endpoint for notification, queue&table for work dispatch?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, endpoints, azure-queues

Let's say I'm not intending to use multiple instances of each role, but rather increase the VM size when load increases.

Idea: Use **internal endpoints** between each role, for sending a notification that role A has put a job for role B in the queue&table (using both, for the roles to ascertain that a job is done at least once and at most once)?

Problem it solves: no role would have to be constantly polling any queue, but instead only polling it upon a notification through the channel between the internal endpoints, and only poll until the queue is empty.

Is this a reasonable solution, or would it bring possible problems?

Or is this just unnecessary overhead given the low transaction costs ($ 0.005  per 100.000 reads?). It would take about 1000.000 transactions per day to reach the cost of an XS worker role instance.

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is that increasing VM size requires redeployment as the VM size is embedded into service package file where as instance count is stored in the service configuration file.

Comment: The time it took to write this post would have paid for 10 years of transactions. I'm not a big fan of complexity unless it is required to solve the problem. If you need a tighter notification window than you can provide with polling, then you can work on a notification system.

Comment: Good point. I was reading this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697709.aspx, but I guess it's a bit outdated.